# Вызов метода класса из DLL c++

Tags: c++

Я когда-то задавал похожий вопрос. Я пытался экспортировать класс, обвернув его в функцию, которая возвращает экземпляр этого класса. Но как можно напрямую экспортировать?

у меня есть класс

```
#pragma once
#include "Headers/Test.h"

class RE_API Test : public A
{
public:
    void B() override;
};
```

---

```
#include "ExampleTest.h"
#include <iostream>

void Test::B()
{
    std::cout << "Its work";
}
```

Эта единица трансляции билдится как .dll

---

```
    auto lib = LoadLibrary(L"assets/scripts/ExampleApp.dll");

    typedef void (*FNPTR)();
    FNPTR myfunc = (FNPTR)GetProcAddress(lib, "Test::B");

    myfunc();
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы вызвать эту функцию сначала необходимо создать экземпляр класса. Чтобы создать экземпляр класса необходимо вызвать конструкутор. С++ не имеет никаких средств для явного обращения к конструктору, он вызывается компилятором автоматически в подходящих контекстах. Кроме того, `GetProcAddress` скорее всего окончится неудачей, так как в таблице имя декорированное и так как тип указателя не совместим с методом класса `Test`.

Comment: То есть, это все равно придется обвернуть в функцию что-то типа `Create`, которая вернет этот класс? Можно как-то сделать в базовом классе функцию, которая получит всех наследников и вернет все эти классы?

Comment: @justdo Которая вернет не класс, а указатель на экземпляр базового класса с динамическим временем хранения. И еще одна функция, которая будет принимать этот указатель для уничтожения. Иначе библиотеку все равно придется линковать к вызывающему коду, чтобы тот мог иметь возможность вызвать деструктор и т.п.